# PySimpleGUI tabgroup alternatives

Tags: pysimplegui

In the application I'm working on, I currently have a tabgroup, but the tabgroup has far too many tabs, and when I checked the documentation, it doesn't seem that there's a way to implement scrolling through the list of tabs. Is there another element in pysimpleGUI or a combination of several, which could be used to select which information to display?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a scrollable container, like `Column` element here.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def new_tab(index):
    return sg.Tab(
        f'Tab {index}',
        [[sg.Text(' ~ '.join(f'This is Tab {index}' for k in range(10)))] for j in range(5)],
        key=f'Tab {index}')
tabgroup = sg.TabGroup(
    [[new_tab(i) for i in range(20)]],
    key='Tabgroup')
layout = [
    [sg.Column(
        [[tabgroup]],
        scrollable=True,                # Scrollable Column
        vertical_scroll_only=False,     # With both of vrtical and horizontal scrollbar
        size_subsample_height=1,        # height same as height of tabgroup
        size_subsample_width=2,         # 1/2 width as width of tabgroup
        key='Column')],
]
window = sg.Window('Scrollable TabGroup', layout, finalize=True)    # window finalized required
# Hide the vertical scrollbar if not necessary, no such option for scrollable Column element at this moment
window['Column'].vsb.pack_forget()
window.read(close=True)
```

[image]